# PHP Checking backwards in a loop, and writing conditions to avoid consecutive values with array_rand()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, random

**My solution is posted below as an answer**

However I will not accept my answer as the correct one. I would really appreciate any help or advice on optimizing my posted solution. I will accept the most helpful answer as the correct one. Thanks for your help!

---

In a wordpress theme in a blog template, I am creating post previews using featured images in three sizes, small medium and large.

The following code does a great job of randomizing the display of the different sizes, I would like to avoid having three or more consecutive posts with the same size.

That is to say, if there are two "mediums" in a row, then the next one should either be small or large, after which the randomization can start again for subsequent array items. This would mean removing the "consecutive" value out of the $thumbs array, then adding it back in for the next iteration.

```
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 

$thumbsize = get('thumb_size');

$thumbs = array();

$thumbs[0] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'locations-small');
$thumbs[1] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'locations-med');
$thumbs[2] = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'locations');

$thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);

if($thumbsize == 'Small'){
    $thumb = $thumb[0];
} elseif($thumbsize == 'Medium') {
    $thumb = $thumb[1];
} elseif($thumbsize == 'Large') {
    $thumb = $thumb[2];
} else {
    $thumb = $thumbs[array_rand($thumbs)];
}

// so on and so forth
```

I understand this would require checking two items backwards in the "if($wp_query)" loop, but am not sure how to do this...

How can I write conditional code to avoid consecutive values using array_rand() ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution. I used multiple counters to check for consecutive values, and reset the counters after the "consecutive limit" was reached.

If anyone has **any** advice on how to further optimize this code, I would certainly accept the most helpful response as the correct answer. Thank you!

```
// three counters for medium, small and large
$ism = 0;
$im = 0;
$il = 0;

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'paged' => $paged
);

query_posts( $args ); 

if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
    $thumbsize = get('thumb_size');

    $thumbs = array();

    $thumbsmall = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'locations-small');
    $thumbmed = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'locations-med');
    $thumblarge = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'locations');

    // If no consecutive sizes have been counted, include all sizes in the array
    if($ism != 2 && $im != 2 && $il != 2) {
        $thumbs[0] = $thumbsmall;
        $thumbs[1] = $thumbmed;
        $thumbs[2] = $thumblarge;
    }

    $thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);

    if($thumbsize == 'Small'){
        $thumb = $thumb[0];
    } elseif($thumbsize == 'Medium') {
        $thumb = $thumb[1];
    } elseif($thumbsize == 'Large') {
        $thumb = $thumb[2];
    } else {
        $thumb = $thumbs[array_rand($thumbs)];
    }

    // Check if each thumb size has been used and if that size occured in the previous iteration, if so, increment the counter, else reset the count to zero
    if($thumb == $thumbsmall && $ism <= 1) {$ism++;} else {$ism = 0;}
    if($thumb == $thumbmed && $im <= 1) {$im++;} else {$im = 0;}
    if($thumb == $thumblarge && $il <= 1) {$il++;} else {$il = 0;}

    // If there are two consecutive sizes, remove one item from the array and reset the counter to zero
    if($ism == 2) {
        $thumbs[0] = $thumblarge;
        $thumbs[1] = $thumbmed;
        $ism = 0;
    }

    if($im == 2) {
        $thumbs[0] = $thumbsmall;
        $thumbs[1] = $thumblarge;
        $im = 0;
    }

    if($il == 2) {
        $thumbs[0] = $thumbmed;
        $thumbs[1] = $thumbsmall;
        $il = 0;
    }

    // So on and so forth
```